Fisher claims Σ(x - λ)²/λ is chi-squared when x is Poisson – how is that?
Quoting from Statistical Methods from Research Workers (11th edition I think, from the 1950s):

From a single sample of 5 it would be impossible to demonstrate that the distribution followed the Poisson series; however, when a large number of such samples have been obtained under comparable conditions, it is possible to utilise the fact that for all Poisson series the variance is numerically equal to the mean.
For each set of parallel plates with $x_1$, $x_2$, ..., $x^n$ colonies respectively, after finding the mean $\bar{x}$, an index of dispersion may be calculated by the formula
$$\chi^2 = \frac{S(x - \bar{x})^2}{\bar{x}}$$
It has been shown that for true samples of a Poisson series, $\chi^2$ calculated in this way will be ditsributed in a known manner; [...] with $n$ equal to one less than the number of parallel plates.

I'm not at all sure what Fisher means by this, but I have interpreted the quantity $S(x - \bar{x})^2$ as the sample variance of the $n$ counts times the number $n$ of counts. This means, unless I'm mistaken,
$$\chi^2 = \frac{n\mathrm{Var}(x)}{\bar{x}}$$
This could be interpreted either as $n$ times what Wikipedia calls the index of dispersion, or the variance of the sum of counts divided by the sample mean.
Is this interpretation correct? I'm struggling to find other references to this computation on the web, so I have a vague feeling I'm doing something wrong.

@YvesDaoust It denotes summation $\sum$, which is a common notation in Fisher's era.

Fisher's wording is an index of dispersion, not the index of dispersion. There could be different reasonable measures of dispersion. It's not surprising that Fisher's choice of Pearson's $\chi^2$ statistic is different than the Wikipedia's.

The statistic
$$T = \frac{1}{\bar X} \sum_{i=1}^n (X_i - \bar X)^2, \tag{1}$$
is what Fisher is referring to, and the assertion is that $$T \sim \chi^2_{n-1},$$ i.e. $T$ is chi-square distributed with $n-1$ degrees of freedom.  However, this is not actually true, if you think about the support of $(1)$.  If the $X_i$ are iid Poisson, then their support is on the set of nonnegative integers, hence the statistic $T$ must have a discretized support.  To make it very obvious that this is the case, choose $n = 2$:  then $$T = \frac{(X_1 - X_2)^2}{X_1 + X_2} \in \mathbb Q \tag{2}$$ identically, even after ignoring cases where $X_1 = X_2 = 0$ which occurs with positive probability $e^{-2\lambda}$.  Simply increasing the sample size cannot remedy this issue.
However, that is not to say that the asymptotic distribution for sufficiently large $n$ is not well-modeled with a $\chi^2$ variable.  The situation is much the same as how the sum of iid Bernoulli variables is exactly binomially distributed, which for sufficiently large $n$, is well-approximated by a normal distribution; only here, the limiting distribution is $\chi^2_{n-1}$.  A proof is left as an exercise for the reader (hint:  the chi-square distribution arises from the sum of iid standard normal random variables; if $\lambda$ sufficiently large, $X_i$ is approximately normal with mean and variance $\mu = \sigma^2 = \lambda$.)
Which parameters control the "goodness" of the approximation?  In the binomial/normal case, when $n$ is small, the approximation is poor.  But it is also poor when $p$ is close to $0$ or $1$.  In the case of the statistic $T$, the continuous approximation improves with increasing $\lambda$, not just with increasing $n$.
